# How to declare the return Type of a grouping Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

What is the type that the following query returns:

```
var photos = job.Photos.GroupBy(x => x.Location)
        .Select(group =>
            new
            {
                Name = group.Key,
                Photos = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded)
            })
        .OrderBy(group => group.Name)
        .ToList();
```

According to the debugger it is of type:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Name, System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Project.Models.Photo> Photos>>'
```

but I don't know how to declare this type.

I've tried

```
public List<string, IOrderedEnumerable<Photo>> Photos {get; set;)
```

But List can only take one element

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is there a type with "name" and "photos" as properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dictionary to hold the string key and list of photos as values, if you don't want to create another class, just to hold this information.

```
IDictionary<string, List<Photo>> photos = job.Photos.GroupBy(x => x.Location)
        .Select(group =>
            new
            {
                Name = group.Key,
                Photos = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded)
            })
        .OrderBy(group => group.Name)
        .ToDictionary(kv=>kv.Name, kv=>kv.Photos.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have couple options:

- you could create your class to hold both the grouping key and the collection of values associated with it. And create an instance of that class instead of anonymous types.
- you could use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`with `Value`being `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`

```
var photos = job.Photos
                .GroupBy(x => x.Location)
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
                              group => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded));
```

I'd add an extra `ToList` call after `OrderByDescending` to prevent for the items to be resolved and sorted just once.

Comment: group.key and group.OrderBy are erroring as group is undefined, am I missing something else here?

Comment: @Evonet yes. the ToDictionary needs to be like this .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded));

Answer (score 0):

As the debugger says, it's an *anonymous type*. That means that you can't write its name, because it doesn't have one. What you can do is to create a new class and use that in your query:

```
List<PhotosGroup> photos = job.Photos.GroupBy(x => x.Location)
        .Select(group =>
            new PhotosGroup
            {
                Name = group.Key,
                Photos = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded)
            })
        .OrderBy(group => group.Name)
        .ToList();
```

Or you could use the `Tuple` type:

```
List<Tuple<string, IOrderedEnumerable<Photo>> photos = job.Photos.GroupBy(x => x.Location)
        .Select(group =>
            Tuple.Create(
                group.Key,
                group.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded)))
        .OrderBy(group => group.Item1)
        .ToList();
```